# rss.xml file in app folder of Nextjs13 goes to 404 after deploying to Vercel

Tags: next.js, rss, vercel

I encountered an issue on my blog.I have a directory named "rss" under the "app" directory, and there is a file that returns an XML. The code is as follows:

```
import RSS from 'rss'
import getPostMetadata from '@/lib/getPostMetadata'

export async function GET() {
  const articles = getPostMetadata();
  const SITE_URL = "https://www.domain.xx";

  const feed = new RSS({
    title: 'xxx',
    description: 'xxx',
    site_url: SITE_URL,
    feed_url: `${SITE_URL}/rss.xml`,
    language: 'zh-cn',
  })

  articles.forEach((article) => {
    feed.item({
      title: article.title,
      description: article.description,
      date: article.date,
      url: `${SITE_URL}/blog/${article.slug}`,
      guid: `${SITE_URL}/blog/${article.slug}`,
    });
  });

  return new Response(feed.xml(), {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/xml",
    },
  });
}
```

everything works perfectly, both locally, and deployed to vercel, I can jump to https://www.domain.xx/rss.xml via rss icon on the homepage, but after deploying to vercel, although I can access https://www.domain.xx/rss.xml, the But after deploying to vercel, although I can access , I get an error on the console:

```
GET https://www.domain.xx/rss.xml?_rsc=1ag7k 404 (Not Found)
```

I am not sure why there is `? _rsc=1ag7k` comes up

This makes me very uncomfortable, also Best Practices in my lighthouse analysis came up with ”Browser errors were logged to the console“.

how do I fix it?

Here is my app directory

```
app
├─layout.tsx
├─page.tsx
├─rss.xml
|    └route.tsx
```

nextjs, rss version here:

```json
"rss": "^1.2.2"
"next": "13.4.10",
```

the console to report error disappear